# What is the best way to calculate with two different and independent tables?

Tags: python, sql-server, algorithm, pyodbc, vertica

I have two different tables located in two independent DB's and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do some calculations.

The first table contains columns: site (varchar 256), website traffic (integer), type of site (varchar 256). Second table contains: site (varchar 256), monthly cost (float), type of site (varchar 256).

*So far I have the query results, but am stumped on how to do the actual analysis, which basically consists of multiplying the website traffic and monthly cost (a simplified example), while using the site and type of site as a key*.

Now if these were two different tables on the same DB I could just do a simple join and be on my merry way. However, this isn't possible. Thus, I'm wondering what would be the most pythonic way to handle this.

Brainstorming on my part has consisted of exporting the first query as a csv then making a temp table in the second database and just doing the analysis there. If there is a better way to do the work in python please let me know.

***My code:***

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=xyx;DATABASE=xxy;UID=xyx;PWD=xyx')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select * from sites;")

rows = cursor.fetchall()

with open('file.txt' , 'w') as f:
    for row in rows:
        csv.writer(f).writerows(row)

cursor.close()
del cursor
conn.close()

conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{Vertica}', server='blah', database='yys', port=5433, 
    uid='zzx', pwd='zzx')

cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select * from table1;")

with open('otherfile.txt' , 'w') as f:
    for row in rows:
        csv.writer(f).writerows(row)

cursor.close()
del cursor
conn.close()
```

Comment: Can you link to the second SQL Server from the first one?  If so, then you can just copy the second table over to the first SQL Server temporarily and then do the Join.

Comment: I can't unfortunately, that's the reason for the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using Python's data analysis package, [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) which can read in queries from SQL databases into dataframes. Then merge both dataframes by the unique fields or or concatenate both dataframes if columns align in names.

Additionally, you can run other sophisticated analysis (i.e., [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html), [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html)) and output dataframe with [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) or [to_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) as new table in SQL database.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

# FIRST DATA FRAME      
conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};\                      
                        SERVER=xyx;DATABASE=xxy;UID=xyx;PWD=xyx')
ssqlsite_df = pd.read_sql("select * from sites;", conn)
conn.close()

# SECOND DATA FRAME
conn = pyodbc.connect(driver='{Vertica}', server='blah', \
                      database='yys', port=5433, uid='zzx', pwd='zzx')
vertsite_df = pd.read_sql("select * from table1;", conn)
conn.close()

# MERGE DATA FRAMES
finaldf = merge(ssqlsite_df, vertsite_df, on=['SiteName', 'TypeOfSite'])

# CONCATENATE/STACK DATA FRAMES 
# (ASSUMING COLUMNS ARE SAME NAME, ADJUST IN QUERY FIELD ALIASES)
finaldf = concat([ssqlsite_df, vertsite_df], axis=0)  

print(finaldf.head(10))    # FIRST TEN ROWS

# DATA ANALYSIS
# CALCULATED COLUMN
finaldf['SiteCost'] = finaldf['WebsiteTraffic'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) * \
                      finaldf['MonthlyCost'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)     
... 

# OUTPUT DATA FRAME
# CREATES NEW TABLE IF PERMISSION GRANTED. BE SURE TO RE-OPEN CONNECTION.
# finaldf.to_sql('SiteAnalysis', conn)  

finaldf.to_csv('C:\\Path\\To\\SiteAnalysis.csv')
```